# Parent LinearLayout not filling to ScrollView at the bottom part

Tags: android, scrollview

[image]

Hi,

As you can see from the image above, the parent LinearLayout is not filling until the bottom of the scroll view (in blue). I chose to put the scroll view at the bottom because the LinearLayout has a ListView.

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/finalImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_01_big" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgFinal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInfoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgFinal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalInfoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="infoTitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgFinal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalInfoDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="infoDesc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgFinal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalLineUpStatic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Line Up"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/finalListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Scroll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutInfo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight=".94"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

    </ListView>





    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lin_Scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rel_Scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Rel_add_gps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="65dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelGPS"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RelAddress" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalGPSStatic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="GPS"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalGPS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalGPSStatic"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/finalGPSStatic"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="click"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelAddress"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalAddressStatic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Address"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalAddressStatic"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/finalAddressStatic"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="not static"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Rel_ven_dat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/Rel_add_gps"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                 >

                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelDate"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RelVenue" 

                android:background="@color/blue"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalDateStatic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalDateStatic"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/finalDateStatic"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="not static"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalDateStatic"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/finalDate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="not static"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelVenue"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalVenueStatic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="not static"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/finalVenue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalVenueStatic"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/finalVenueStatic"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="not static"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelButtonTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.45" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:text="Button" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
            android:text="Button" />

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="2.45" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
                android:text="Button" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.45" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:text="Button" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
            android:text="Button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 11" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the xml instead.

Comment: Not "instead" but "along with"

Comment: @codeMagic : I mean, the xml will be more informative instead of the image :)

Comment: @IndexOutOfBounds I assumed as much but wanted to make sure the OP didn't remove the image. Those are usually pretty important with layout questions.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes! Agreed.

Comment: @TwoStarll I'm not sure what the problem is exactly. Your root LL is taking upt the whole screen. Your SV is taking up from where it starts to the bottom. Also, that's a big layout. Not sure what you're doing but you may want to consider using `<include>`. It might help with adjustments in the future.